# Electron: Maximized browserWindow overlaps Window' taskbar

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have problems with Electron BrowserWindow because when I call the function: win.maximize() the app overlaps Window' taskbar as if it were in full screen mode, but I set fullScreen: false.

Here's the links of the screenshots!
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a7b8h8ukaz4pf26/default%20window%20size.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wf0jcv5kp04c25/maximized%20window.png?dl=0

Here's my code:

main.js (the default electron window setting):

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

let mainWindow;

app.on('window-all-closed', function(){
    // Notice on OS X the application don't close when you quit window
    // Darwin is the platform name when OS X in loaded
    if(process.platform != 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('ready', function() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 700,
        height: 450,
        frame: false,
        resizable: false,
        backgroundColor: '#333333',
        'node-integration': true
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
    mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
});
```

default.js (it handles windows button: minimize, maximize and close):

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;

(function(){
    function init(){
        document.getElementById('minimize-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
            var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            window.minimize();
        });

        document.getElementById('maximize-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
            var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            if (!window.isMaximized()) {
                window.maximize();
            } else {
                window.unmaximize();
            }
        });

        document.getElementById('close-btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
            var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
            window.close();
        });
    }

    init();
})();
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That must be why I remembered running into a similar issue and not knowing how it was fixed. Someone should open an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/electron/electron) if a similar issue doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked this functionality on my own electron app using Windows 10 and it doesn't overlap the taskbar, even though I have a function with almost the exact same code:

```
function toggleMaximize() {
  var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
  if(window.isMaximized()) {
    window.unmaximize();
  } else {
    window.maximize();
  }
```

These are my BrowserWindow settings, which are also fairly similar:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  width: windowState.width,
  height: windowState.height,
  x: windowState.x,
  y: windowState.y,
  show: false,
  frame: false,
  transparent: false
});
```

Where windowState just stores/restores the previous position and size of the application window.

Comment: Hi Stevenson!
I reused your code and implement the window-state package but it doesn't work.
I tested on Window 7 and 8 and it's the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it by this way:

First, run the application setting a window with frame: **true**, close it, and then run it with frame: **false**. That's it! I don't know if it was a bug.

This question can be closed.